# Meaning of 'wasn't for nine days'

Tags: meaning-in-context

**The rain fell and his next appointment wasn't for nine days.**

It means his appointment will start after nine days?

Comment: Probably, but you haven't supplied any context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've glanced at the source text,
[google search "The End of the Day"](https://books.google.com/books?id=gn_UDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT95&dq=%22the%20rain%20fell%20and%20his%20next%20appointment%20wasn%27t%20for%20nine%20days%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg55n2za_oAhVJCs0KHZo5BCUQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20rain%20fell%20and%20his%20next%20appointment%20wasn't%20for%20nine%20days%22&f=false)

It does mean what you said, but it means a little more when expressed negatively. It means there were nine days that he must wait before his next appointment.
The focus of the statement is on the nine days, which is a frustrating delay because he is looking forward to the appointment.

If someone had an appointment that they feared, the nine days might be seen as a welcome delay, for example, "My next chemotherapy appointment isn't for nine days."